# Maven dependency version not same

Tags: java, maven

I have some spring-boot common library with hazelcast dependency:

```
mvn dependency:tree
[INFO] org.my.project:something-common:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.hazelcast:hazelcast:jar:3.9:compile
[INFO] +- com.hazelcast:hazelcast-client:jar:3.9:compile
```

and main project with dependency on this common library

```
mvn dependency:tree
[INFO] \- org.my.project:something-common:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    +- com.hazelcast:hazelcast:jar:3.7.8:compile
[INFO]    \- com.hazelcast:hazelcast-client:jar:3.7.8:compile
```

why hazelcast version is not same as in my common library and why it takes version from spring-boot parent pom?

Comment: ... it's not the same, because the dependency versions set in the pom files are not the same. remember, you are working with a SNAPSHOT, a SNAPSHOT is not a fixed (release) version, it can alter over time

Answer (score 0):

Because the version of dependence Hazelcast has been changed. You are using SNAPSHOT version (in-working version).

Comment: This is an example of upgrade version of Hazelcast in Spring Boot: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/ac10fa31cdd3085dcf113df4802c35df595f02b7#diff-c32bf1f3938108ba1abd76d4a9f7d19b